# Wrapping article text around an element in Seblod with Joomla

Tags: joomla

I'm using Seblod to build an article page for my joomla site, and I want to get the text to wrap round this youtube video. The text is in the left column, and the video is in the right. At the minute the video just rests on top of the text. Does anyone know how to get the text to wrap around an element?

This is what the article looks like currently. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaqYV.jpg

Comment: Can you provide some sample code that you're using?

Comment: Yes. You have used a CSS tag for your question so paste you CSS and also the HTML

Comment: @jessica, by the way. You look hot

Comment: You can put your code in jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I can't access the css because its generated by the Seblod CCK. Sorry I probably shouldn't have used the css tag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add your video using the content editor:

```html
<p>
<p style="float:right;">VIDEO_CODE</p>
<p>some text</p>
</p>
```